# Dynamic Array List size

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic

How can I set size of a dynamic array with Java?

I tried `setsize(...)` with the array variable but not working. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

array size needs to be fixed while initialization, use [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead and then have array from [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) using [`toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29)

For example:

```
List<Integer> listOfInt = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //no fixed size mentioned
listOfInt .add(1);
listOfInt .add(2);
listOfInt .add(3);
//now convert it to array 
Integer[] arrayOfInt = list.toArray(new Integer[listOfInt .size()]);
```

Comment: Maybe suggest `ArrayList` in particular, since it actually uses an array under the hood?

Comment: Yes you could use `ArrayList` implementation as @Tudor mentioned in comment

Comment: List<Integer>[911] A = new ArrayList<Integer>();  but says it is not statement, im confused

Comment: Added example, it would help more

Answer (score 1):

Your title is confusing.  Are you using an ArrayList or an Array.
An `ArrayList` expands and shrinks as needed each time you call the `add`, `remove` method respectively (or any other add/remove variant). There is no need to manage its size yourself.

A list is initialized as follows:

```
List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Now you have a list where you can add a virtual infinite amount of elements.

An `array` needs its size on initialization which cannot be changed without reinitializing.

Comment: +1 Almost surely the OP is trying to ask about `ArrayList`, but it's confusing.